# "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.0", mismatch with angular material "@angular/material": "^13.1.1",

Tags: ecmascript-6, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular12, mjs

Don't say "downgrade version" to this question. I cant do it because management want to maintain the latest versions. Is there any other alternatives...like converting mjs to js file in angular project?

Getting error during "ng serve"

[image: Treminal output after "ng serve"]

My packaje.json include below dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~11.1.1",
"@angular/cdk": "^12.2.0",
"@angular/common": "~11.1.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~11.1.1",
"@angular/core": "^11.2.14",
"@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
"@angular/forms": "~11.1.1",
"@angular/localize": "~11.1.1",
"@angular/material": "^13.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~11.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.1.1",
"@angular/router": "~11.0.4",
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.7.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
"@googlemaps/js-api-loader": "^1.12.9",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.1",
"@passbase/button": "^3.2.0",
"@types/mixpanel-browser": "^2.35.7",
"@types/react": "^17.0.34",
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
"bs-stepper": "^1.7.0",
"crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
"file-saver": "^2.0.5",
"firebase": "^8.6.2",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"mixpanel-browser": "^2.41.0",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
"ng-multiselect-dropdown": "1.0.0-beta.15",
"ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
"ngx-file-drop": "^11.1.0",
"ngx-image-cropper": "^3.3.5",
"ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
"ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
"ngx-toastr": "^14.0.0",
"pusher-js": "^7.0.3",
"rxjs": "~6.5.5",
"tslib": "^2.2.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.3"
},




 "devDependencies": {
"@types/node": "^12.20.13",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
"firebase-tools": "^8.0.0",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~4.1.3"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the below official Angular guide on upgrading from version X to version Y.

https://update.angular.io/

It seems that your upgrade process did not work accurately for some reason.